# Circular modules: Expected {} to be a GraphQL type

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I came across this issue called module cycles when requiring modules.
Im working on a small star wars graphql api and ill explain in short where i got the issue :
I have two type : filmType and charecterType:

film.js:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
} = require("graphql");

const specieType = require("./specie");
const starshipType = require("./starship");
const vehicleType = require("./vehicle");
const charecterType = require("./charecter");
const planetType = require("./planet");

const getFilteredData = require("../util/loader");

module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Film",
  fields: () => ({
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    episode_id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    opening_crawl: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    director: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    producer: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    release_date: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    species: {
      type: new GraphQLList(specieType),
      resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
        return getFilteredData(film.species);
      },
    },
    starships: {
      type: new GraphQLList(starshipType),
      resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
        return getFilteredData(film.starships);
      },
    },
    vehicles: {
      type: new GraphQLList(vehicleType),
      resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
        return getFilteredData(film.vehicles);
      },
    },
    characters: {
      type: new GraphQLList(charecterType),
      resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
        return getFilteredData(film.characters);
      },
    },
    planets: {
      type: new GraphQLList(planetType),
      resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
        return getFilteredData(film.planets);
      },
    },
    created: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    edited: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
});
```

And charecter.js:

```
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLList } = require("graphql");

const getFilteredData = require("../util/loader");

const filmType = require("./film");

module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Character",
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: "Name of the film character",
    },
    height: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    mass: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    hair_color: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    skin_color: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    eye_color: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    birth_year: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    gender: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    // TODO: module cycles problem
    films: {
      type: new GraphQLList(filmType),
      resolve: (character, parent, args) => {
        console.log(character);
        return [];
      },
    },
    url: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    created: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    edited: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
  }),
});
```

And the file that contains the rootQuery:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLList,
} = require("graphql");

//TODO: Search a solution on how to avoid one ugly file with all types combined!!!!
const filmType = require("./swapi-res/film");
const characterType = require("./swapi-res/charecter");

module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQuery",
  fields: {
    film: {
      type: filmType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
      },
      resolve: async (parent, args) => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://swapi.dev/api/films/${args.id}/`);
        return res.data;
      },
    },

    films: {
      type: new GraphQLList(filmType),
      resolve: async (parent, args) => {
        const res = await axios.get("http://swapi.dev/api/films/");
        return res.data.results;
      },
    },

    character: {
      type: characterType,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLID,
        },
      },
      resolve: async (parent, args) => {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${args.id}/`);
        return res.data;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

So eventually filmType type is requiring charecterType and charecterType is requiring filmType , because film can have many characters and character can play in many films.

The solutions iv looked on until now is to **combine** all of the types into **ONE FILE**

So i tried that and it seems to work, **but** im sure there is another way to fix this issue without making one ugly file with all the type.

How do I solve this issue ? (if more info is needed let me know)

Comment: You'll need to pass a function that returns the type to solve the circular dependency of constructing the `new GraphQLObjectType`s. This is unrelated to whether or not the types are created in a single file or not.

Comment: In addition, you need to avoid top-level `require` statements in modules with circular dependencies (or at least use exports properties, not a single export). ES modules solve this better.

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i found , instead of requiring the film.js at the top of the charecter.js file what i did was this:

```
const characterType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Character",
  fields: () => {
    const filmType = require("./film"); **// Inclue the require inside fields**
    return {
      name: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: "Name of the film character",
      },
      height: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      mass: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      hair_color: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      skin_color: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      eye_color: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      birth_year: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      gender: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      films: {
        type: new GraphQLList(filmType),
        resolve: (people, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(people.films);
        },
      },
      url: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      created: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      edited: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
    };
  },
});

module.exports = characterType;
```

same thing on films.js file:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
} = require("graphql");

const specieType = require("./specie");
const starshipType = require("./starship");
const vehicleType = require("./vehicle");
const planetType = require("./planet");
const getFilteredData = require("../util/loader");

const filmType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Film",
  fields: () => {
    const charecterType = require("./charecter"); **// Include inside the fields instead of at the top of the file**
    return {
      title: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      episode_id: {
        type: GraphQLInt,
      },
      opening_crawl: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      director: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      producer: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      release_date: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      characters: {
        type: new GraphQLList(charecterType),
        resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(film.characters);
        },
      },
      planets: {
        type: new GraphQLList(planetType),
        resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(film.planets);
        },
      },
      species: {
        type: new GraphQLList(specieType),
        resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(film.species);
        },
      },
      starships: {
        type: new GraphQLList(starshipType),
        resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(film.starships);
        },
      },
      vehicles: {
        type: new GraphQLList(vehicleType),
        resolve: (film, parent, args) => {
          return getFilteredData(film.vehicles);
        },
      },
      created: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
      edited: {
        type: GraphQLString,
      },
    };
  },
});

module.exports = filmType;
```

Can you please let me know if this is an ok solution or i can do better ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's ok, but I would recommend to go ahead and move *all* the type `require()`s into the function, so that the problem won't happen again when you add new types, change the order, or require a different module first.

Comment: Btw the singular of "species" is "species"

Comment: Thank you bergi , will do ill move all the require since i started with the two type that caused the problem

Comment: By the way , how can I log all of the request when i query the data ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that